# Perron's method for the Dirichlet Problem: how to show that a given function is an upper barrier

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to study Perron's method for the Dirichlet Problem and would like to solve the following exercise: Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, bounded domain that satisfies an exterior sphere condition, that is for every point $\xi \in \partial U$ there exists a ball $B= B_R(y)$ satisfying $\bar{B} \cap \bar{U}=\{\xi\}$. Given such  $\xi$ and $B$, show that the function $w(x)= R^{2-n} - |x-y|^{2-n},$ for $n \geq 3$ and $log(|x-y|/R)$ for $n=2$ is an upper barrier (for the Laplacian) at $\xi$. (that is show that $w>0$ in $\bar{U}-\{\xi\} , w(\xi)=0 $ and $w$ superharmonic in $U$). Could please show me a solution for this?, Thank you very much

Comment: @Michał Miśkiewicz first we show (i) $w>0$ in $\bar{U}-\{\xi\}$. In the case $n=2$ we know that the logarithm is always $>0$, but in the case $n \geq 3$ I can't see why $R^{2-n}-|x-y|^{2-n}$ has to be $>0$. Now we want to show (ii) $w(x)=0$ but why is $w(\xi)=R^{2-n}-|\xi - y|^{2-n}$ equal to zero? And in the case $n=2$ I don't get why $log(|\xi -y|/R)=0$ either.

Comment: @Michał Miśkiewicz Now to part (iii) we have to show $\Delta w \leq 0$ So we compute (I don't know if my computations are correct) $\Delta w = \Delta (R^{2-n}) - \Delta |x-y|^{2-n}$ now the laplacian of a constant is zero so we have $\Delta w = 0 - \Delta |x-y|^{2-n} = -(\partial_1^2|x-y|^{2-n}+\partial_2^2|x-y|^{2-n})$

Comment: @Michał Miśkiewicz Now we know $\partial_i |x|=x_i/|x|$ so by the chain rule we get $\partial_1^2|x-y|^{2-n} = \partial_1(\partial_1 |x-y|^{2-n}) = \partial_1[(2-n) |x-y|^{1-n}(x_1-y_1)/|x-y|]=\partial_1 [(2-n)|x-y|^{-n}(x_1-y_1)]=\partial_1(|x-y|^{-n})=-n|x-y|^{-n-1}(x_1-y_1)/|x-y| =-n|x-y|^{-n-2}(x_1-y_1)$ Now the second summand is symmetric, so $\partial^2_2 |x-y|^{2-n}=-n|x-y|^{-n-2}(x_2-y_2)$ And so $\Delta w=-[-n|x-y|^{-n-2}(x_1-y_1+x_2-y_2)]$ and I don't see why this is $\leq 0$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I suggest that you edit your original question and include this clarification (it would be more readable to others). Your calculation was correct up to $\partial_1 [(2-n)|x-y|^{-n}(x_1-y_1)]$, then something went wrong ($\Delta w$ should be zero).

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to be very clear.

[https://math.rice.edu/~hardt/521F02/perron.pdf](https://math.rice.edu/%7Ehardt/521F02/perron.pdf)

He starts by taking pointwise supremums of subharmonic functions to get u. In step 3, he wants to show that u coincides with a harmonic function h at a countable number of points in a ball.

He needs to find a single h that works for all the above countable points. He uses the diagonal method where at the nth step, he takes the max of the nth subharmonic functions for the first n points and lifts it to a harmonic function on a slightly bigger ball. (For intuition on lifting, recall the Cauchy integral formula for a ball.)

So now he has a sequence of harmonic functions on a ball. The mean value theorem and the Cauchy integral formula can be used to show that this sequence is equicontinuous on a smaller ball. You can then use the Arzela Ascoli theorem to find a subsequence that converges. You can next use the Cauchy integral formula, interchange the limit and the integral using the dominated convergence theorem, and show that the limit is harmonic on the smaller ball. See https://www.axler.net/HFT.pdf

Since any subharmonic function can be lifted on a ball to a harmonic function which is by definition subharmonic, the supremums h and u coincide on the countable set. He then shows $h=u$ for all points on the ball using continuity and dense countable subset arguments.

Finally, he uses the barrier condition to create a subharmonic and a superharmonic function as described above that sandwich u at a boundary point. He squeezes the sandwich and gets u to have the correct boundary values. (Note that harmonicity is an open ball property. On the boundary, all we need is continuity.)

https://people.bath.ac.uk/mw2319/ma40203/sec-perron.html